# What is the probability of a tennis player winning both, or one of two sets?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Let's suppose we are calculating tennis, where two sets are played.

- The probability of player "A" winning the first set is 50%
- The probability of player "A" winning the second set is 50% (regardless of winning the first set or not, so no dependence)

What is the probability of

1. Player "A" winning at least 1 of the 2 sets.
2. Player "A" Winning both of the sets.

I am not sure in my method of calculating this, so please explain it.

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There are four possible mutually exclusive outcomes, where W represents player A winning a set and L his losing it, being WW; WL; LW; LL.

The win or loss of the second set is independent of the first and so p(WL) = p(W)p(L), etc.

Since p(L) = p(W) = 0.5 then the probabilities of each of the four outcomes are all the same and = 0.25 (i.e. 0.5 * 0.5)

Then the probability of A winning at least one set is p(WL) + p(LW) + p(WW) =0.75.
And the probability for A to win both is p(WW) = 0.25

Comment: Then my thinking methodology was right! Thank you very much! Have a nice day/good night!